# Remove duplicate substrings from two strings

Tags: ruby

I am writing a script to remove the longest duplicate substrings from two strings. There are two strings: `a` and `b`:

```
a = "Hello World: This is a test message"
b = "Good Bye: This is a test message"
```

Since there are duplicates: `: This is a test message`, they are removed from both strings. I am trying to achieve the output below:

```
"Hello World"
"Good Bye"
```

Another example is:

```
a = "Zoo is awesome. Hello World: This is not a test message"
b = "Zoo is not awesome. Good Bye: This is a test message"
```

with expected output:

```
"Zoo is awesome. Hello World: This is not"
"Zoo is not awesome. Good Bye: This is"
```

I was thinking to split the strings into arrays of substrings and subtract two arrays to get the unique substring. Please advise if there is a better way of doing it.

Comment: Suppose the strings are `"A Hello: The cat is"` and `"A Good Bye: The dog is"`. What is your desired return value? I don't understand whether you want to return just one common string (and if so, which one, if there are several--the longest?) or all common strings (which presumably would be all common words). Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: In your edit why isn't `" a test message"` and/or `" This is "` removed from both strings?

Comment: It now appears you are just removing the common bits at the ends of both strings. Is that correct? Also, are the matches to be case sensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to find the longest common substring, then subtract it. To find the longest common substring you need to know all substrings:

```
def substrings(string)
  (0..string.length-1).flat_map do |i|
    (1..string.length-i).flat_map do |j|
      string[i,j]
    end
  end
end
```

This is done by starting at index 0 and taking a full-length substring, then a length-1 substring, and so on before moving to index 1 and repeating iteratively.

This returns them in a fairly arbitrary order, though it's trivial to sort by length. The next step is to see which of these matches `all?` items given:

```
def lcs(*list)
  list = list.sort_by(&:length)
  subs = substrings(list.first).sort_by(&:length).reverse

  subs.find do |str|
    list.all? do |entry|
      entry.include?(str)
    end
  end
end
```

Here the shortest entry (sort order `first`) is selected because it will necessarily contain the longest common string.

That gets you the substring you want to delete, so you can apply that:

```
def uniqueify(*list)
  list_lcs = lcs(*list)

  list.map do |entry|
    entry.sub(list_lcs, '')
  end
end
```

Which then works:

```
a = "Hello World: This is a test message"
b = "Good Bye: This is a test message"

lcs(a,b)
# => ": This is a test message"

uniqueify(a,b)
# => ["Hello World", "Good Bye"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Google has a wonderful library called `diff_match_patch`, which makes character-based diffs of two strings in a superfast manner, and - there is a gem for Ruby!

```
require 'diff_match_patch'
longest = DiffMatchPatch.new.diff_main(a, b).    # find diffs
    select { |type, text| type == :equal }.      # select only equal pieces
    map(&:last).                                 # get just text
    max_by(&:length)                             # find the longest one
a[longest] = ''                                  # delete this piece from a
b[longest] = ''                                  #               and from b

puts a
# => Hello world
puts b
# => Good bye
```

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is simply to remove common characters at the ends of both strings we could write:

```
def remove_common_ending(str1, str2)
  return ["", ""] if str1 == str2
  n = [str1.size, str2.size].min
  return [str1, str2] if n.zero?
  i = (1..n).find { |i| str1[-i].downcase != str2[-i].downcase }
  [str1[0..-i], str2[0..-i]]
end

remove_common_ending(str1, str2)
  #=> ["Hello World", "Good Bye"]
```

Another possible interpretation is that the longest common substring is to be removed from both strings. What follows is one way to do that. My approach is similar to @tadman's, except I start with the length of the longest possible common substring, then progressively shorten that length until a substring is found that appears in both strings. That way there's no need to look for shorter matching substrings.

```
def longest_common_substring(str1, str2)
  return '' if str1.empty? || str2.empty?
  s1, s2 = str1.downcase, str2.downcase
  (s1, s2 = s2, s1) if s2.size < s1.size
  sz1 = s1.size
  sz1.downto(1) do |len|
    puts "Checking #{sz1-len+1} substrings of length #{len}..."
    (0..sz1-len).each do |i|
      s = s1[i, len]
      return s if s2.include?(s)
    end
  end 
end
```

I've added a `puts` statement to show what calculations are being performed. Note that I search the longer string (`str1`) for substrings of the shorter string (`str2`).

```
str1 = "Hello World: This is a test message"
str2 = "Good Bye: This is a test message"  

s = longest_common_substring(str1, str2)    
Checking 1 substrings of length 32...
Checking 2 substrings of length 31...
Checking 3 substrings of length 30...
Checking 4 substrings of length 29...
Checking 5 substrings of length 28...
Checking 6 substrings of length 27...
Checking 7 substrings of length 26...
Checking 8 substrings of length 25...
Checking 9 substrings of length 24...
  #=> ": This is a test message"

r = /#{Regexp.escape(s)}/i
  #=> /:\ this\ is\ a\ test\ message/i
str1.sub(r,'') #=> "Hello World"
str2.sub(r,'') #=> "Good Bye"
```

As seen, the number of substrings of the shorter string (`str2`) that were checked before the longest common substring was found was `(1+10)*10/2-1 #=> 54`.

Comment: `str2.match?(/#{s1}/i)` is dangerous, since regexp interpolation will treat control symbols unescaped (try e.g. `str = "\\1"; /#{str}/`). Better use `str2.include?(s1.downcase)`.

Comment: or `/#{Regexp.escape(s1)}/i`

Comment: ...@Amadan. I've incorporated both of your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering to remove only the trail matching substring, using arrays, I came up with this solution:

```
a = "Hello World: This is a test message"
b = "Good Bye: This is a test message"
# a = "Zoo is awesome. Hello World: This is not a test message"
# b = "Zoo is not awesome. Good Bye: This is a test message"

a_ary = a.split(/\b/)
b_ary = b.split(/\b/)

zipped = a_ary.reverse.zip(b_ary.reverse)
dropped = zipped.drop_while { |(a,b)| a == b }

dropped.reverse.transpose.map{|w| w.join('')}
#=> ["Hello World", "Good Bye"]
#=> ["Zoo is awesome. Hello World: This is not", "Zoo is not awesome. Good Bye: This is"]
```

One liner:

```
a.split(/\b/).reverse.zip(b.split(/\b/).reverse).drop_while { |(a,b)| a == b }.reverse.transpose.map{|w| w.join('')}
```